# streaming twitter with tweepy and pyspark

Tags: python, twitter, pyspark

I am trying to stream tweets using pyspark and tweepy library to get the top ten tweets based on number of retweets and likes.

The first step is streaming the tweets using tweepy I streamed the tweets perfectly in pycharm and this is the code :

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import socket
import json

consumer_key = 'consumer_key'
consumer_secret = 'secret_key'
access_token = 'token_key'
access_secret = 'access_secret_key'

class TweetsListener(StreamListener):

  def __init__(self, csocket):
  self.client_socket = csocket

  def on_data(self, data):
      try:
      msg = json.loads( data )
      print( msg['text'].encode('utf-8') )
      self.client_socket.send( 
      msg['text'].encode('utf-8') )
      return True
      except BaseException as e:
      print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
     return True

  def on_error(self, status):
     print(status)
     return True

  def sendData(c_socket):
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, 
   consumer_secret)
   auth.set_access_token(access_token, 
    access_secret)

   twitter_stream = Stream(auth, 
   TweetsListener(c_socket))
    twitter_stream.filter(track= 
    ['iphone'],languages=["en"])

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = socket.socket()       
    host = "192.168.0.12"      
    port = 5555                 
    s.bind((host, port))        

    print("Listening on port: %s" % str(port))

     s.listen(5)                 
   c, addr = s.accept()        

  print( "Received request from: " + str( addr ) )

   sendData( c )
```

Secondly ,this is my pyspark code i run that in jupyter notebook. First the streaming code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext 
sc
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10 )

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
socket_stream = ssc.socketTextStream("192.168.0.12", 5555)
lines = socket_stream.window( 20 )
from collections import namedtuple 

fields = ("tag", "count" )

Tweet = namedtuple( 'Tweet', fields)

(lines.flatMap(lambda text: text.split(" ")).filter(lambda word: word.lower().startswith("#")) 
.map( lambda word: ( word.lower(), 1)) 
.reduceByKey( lambda a, b: a + b) 
.map(lambda rec: Tweet(rec[0], rec[1])) 
.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.toDF().sort(desc("count")).limit(10).registerTempTable("tweets") ))

ssc.start()
```

And then some testing and plotting code:

```
import time
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

count = 0
 while count < 10:

    time.sleep( 3 )

    top_10_tweets = sqlContext.sql( 'Select tag, count from tweets' )
    top_10_df = top_10_tweets.toPandas() 
    display.clear_output(wait=True) #Clears the output, if a plot exists.
    sns.plt.figure( figsize = ( 10, 8 ) )
    sns.barplot( x="count", y="tag", data=top_10_df)
    sns.plt.show()
    count = count + 1
```

but i got this error when i reach the last cell which start with count = 0 until the end :

---

```
---------------------------
 Py4JJavaError                             
     Traceback (most recent call last)
  /usr/local/Cellar/apache-/usr/local/Cellar/apache- 
spark/2.4.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py 
in deco(*a, **kw)
 62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
    64         except 
  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

  /usr/local/Cellar/apache- 
  spark/2.4.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7- 
  src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in 
  get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, 
  target_id, name)
   327                     "An error occurred 
  while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
  --> 328                     format(target_id, 
  ".", name), value)
      329             else:

       AnalysisException: 'Table or view not 
        found: tweets; line 1 pos 23'
```

any idea how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with the code. This problem arises because 'registerTempTable' is not creating the temp view which is named as the 'tweet'. This is not done on the local machine but you have any virtual machine (Ubuntu works perfectly fine) then this will create the temp view.